# Unity: detect if path is clear using Raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, draw, physics, raycasting

Currently my code looks like this:

```
    Vector3 tempPos = transform.position;
    Vector3 checkPos = new Vector3(tempPos.x, tempPos.y, Mathf.Round(tempPos.z + 1));
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        Vector3 direction = checkPos - transform.position;
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, direction);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.point);
        }
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction, Color.black, 20, false);
    }
```

however even when i am right up against an object, I get nothing from my Debug.Log() statement. As a matter of fact, I cannot even call a Debug.DrawRay() statement as it doesn't show anything either. What on Earth could I be doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it possible tempPos.z+1 still appears inside your mesh and you just cant _see_ the ray?

Comment: Is this is an `update()` loop?  Where is this code?  I bet if you put a `Debug.Log` anywhere in that code, even outside of your `if` statements, it won't get hit.  The problem is likely with where the code itself is.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel https://hastebin.com/vupiyidaqi.cs << this is the whole PlayerController.cs class. The method in question is void MovePlayer()

Comment: @MaxvonHippel if i put a Debug.Log() in there instead of the raycast i do see an output in the log. All of the other if() statements are hit as well. the player can move with SAD just not W yet as I am restructuring the method

Comment: Do you have [gizmos](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html) turned on in your scene view?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know the problem from a small snippet but you could try:

```
Vector3 fwd = tempPos.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
if (Physics.Raycast(raycastObject.transform.position, fwd, out objectHit, 50))
{
    Debug.Log("Hit");
}
```